# mail() function takes too long to send email

Tags: php, apache, centos

On my server `(LAMP + CentOS)` I have a page for sending emails using the `mail()` function. My problem is that there's a delay of 1 to 2 minutes in receiving sent mails.

I'm using a simple script to send email:

```
<?php
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com'; mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Test email using PHP', 'This is a test email message', $headers, '-fwebmaster@example.com');
    echo 'complete';
?>
```

[this is my php.ini file](http://pastebin.com/qyPTQYQk)

Comment: nothing php can help... prob belongs to latency or your service provider's

Comment: Try to use Swift Mailer and send mails using gmail.

Comment: @user1844933 , but it is the script that takes two minutes to run, because I see the loading of google chrome it takes 1-2 minutes, when I see the message "Complete" I receive the email within 1-5 second, then do you think the problem is the latency?